# VB.net Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference

Tags: vb.net

So in mist of programing a program I have bee stuck after roughly 6 hours of research and fiddling. I cannot resolve this error.

```
Public Class Main




Private Sub txt1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mstag.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbl1.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub devicepage_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles devicepage.DocumentCompleted

End Sub
Public Class myform

    Private SIS As System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
    Private netdata As NetworkStream
    Private Sub Run_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Run.Click


        Dim msnumber As String = mstag.Text

        'Ping Code

        Try
            Dim ping As Ping = New Ping()
            Dim ping2 As Ping = New Ping()
            Dim ping3 As Ping = New Ping()
            Dim ping4 As Ping = New Ping()
            Dim pingreply As PingReply = ping.Send(mstag.Text + ".regent.edu")
            Dim pingreply2 As PingReply = ping2.Send(mstag.Text + ".regent.edu")
            Dim pingreply3 As PingReply = ping3.Send(mstag.Text + ".regent.edu")
            Dim pingreply4 As PingReply = ping4.Send(mstag.Text + ".regent.edu")
            Dim avgadd As Integer = pingreply.RoundtripTime + pingreply2.RoundtripTime + pingreply3.RoundtripTime + pingreply4.RoundtripTime
            Dim avg As Integer = avgadd / 4
            pingresults.Text &= "Ping Time: " & pingreply.RoundtripTime & "ms" & vbNewLine
            pingresults.Text &= "Ping Time: " & pingreply2.RoundtripTime & "ms" & vbNewLine
            pingresults.Text &= "Ping Time: " & pingreply3.RoundtripTime & "ms" & vbNewLine
            pingresults.Text &= "Ping Time: " & pingreply4.RoundtripTime & "ms" & vbNewLine
            pingresults.Text &= "Average Time: " & (avg) & "ms"

        Catch err As Exception
            pingresults.Text = "Ping Timeout"
        End Try


        'NSLOOKUP Code

        Try
            Dim p As New Process
            With p.StartInfo
                .FileName = "nslookup.exe"
                .Arguments = mstag.Text
                .CreateNoWindow = True
                .RedirectStandardOutput = True
                .RedirectStandardError = True
                .UseShellExecute = False
            End With

            p.Start()
            If p.WaitForExit(5000) Then
                'Read Output
                Dim reader As StreamReader = p.StandardOutput
                Dim output As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
                nslookupresults.Text = output

            Else
                'Failed
                nslookupresults.Text = ("Failed: Timeout")
            End If

        Catch err As Exception
            nslookupresults.Text = "Timeout. :("
        End Try

        'Telnet

        SIS = New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
        SIS.Connect(mstag.Text, 23)
        netdata = SIS.GetStream()

        If netdata.CanWrite And netdata.CanRead Then
            Dim bytes(SIS.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
            netdata.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(SIS.ReceiveBufferSize))
            Dim returndata As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
            telnetout.Text = returndata
        End If

    End Sub


    Public Sub sissend_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles sissend.Click


        Dim myWriteBuffer As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(telnetinput.Text)
        netdata.Write(myWriteBuffer, 0, myWriteBuffer.Length)

        Dim bytes(SIS.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
        netdata.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(SIS.ReceiveBufferSize))
        Dim returndata As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
        telnetout.Text = returndata
    End Sub
End Class
```

The starred/Bold are the problematic pieces.

Updated to newest code from the entire project.

Comment: `NetworkStream` is a Type name, its a bad idea to use variables of the same name; in this case it masks the real problem.  You declared your `networkStream` var *local* to one event so, you cant use it in another. Read up  on [Scope in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx)

Comment: How would I fix this. It makes sense. still new to programming. I'm trying to expand my skill set.

Comment: Here is updated code for easier reading with different names @Plutonix

Comment: Even with a change in casing, that variable name is way too close to the the name of a type. There are so many safe ways to avoid bad things.
MynetworkStream as networkStream  would be safer

Comment: Your code seems to think tha tyou're calling a shared procedure inside of a class. It's not executing because the class networkStream does not have a shared procedure by that name. Change your variables name.

Comment: @I'mStartingToHateThisSite that fixed that error thank you but transitioned to 'SIS' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. FYI I updated post with new code.

Comment: PS. I think you may have a typo at the start of this question. I assume that "In mist of" was supposed to be "In midst of". Not being a Nazi, I just keep scrolling through questions and every time I glance that one I get stuck for a moment.

Comment: Your edits to the code you posted has made some of the comments non-sensical!  The title of your post now no longer matches the problem you are having.  This is discouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do well to never assign a variable the name of a class accessible by your code.

This code block was updated per comments.

```
 Public Sub Run_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Run.Click
    'Telnet

    Dim MYtcpClient As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
    MytcpClient.Connect(mstag.Text, 23)
    Dim MyNetworkStream As NetworkStream = MYtcpClient.GetStream()


    If MyNetworkStream.CanWrite And MyNetworkStream.CanRead Then
        Dim bytes(MYtcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
        MyNetworkStream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(MYtcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize))
        Dim returndata As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
        telnetout.Text = returndata
    End If

End Sub
```

Also, the code below has no new instance of Networkstream or tcpclient and is trying to reference the class directly.   I missed that when I first posted the answer. You'll need to create a new instance of each.

```
Public Sub sissend_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles sissend.Click

 Dim MYtcpClient As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
    MytcpClient.Connect(mstag.Text, 23)
    Dim MyNetworkStream As new NetworkStream
    MyNetworkStream.Write(myWriteBuffer, 0, myWriteBuffer.Length)

    Dim bytes(MYtcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
    MyNetworkStream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(MYtcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize))
    Dim returndata As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
    telnetout.Text = returndata
End Sub
```

Per comments for long term connection

```
Public Class myForm
   Private MYtcpClient As System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
   Private MyNetworkStream As NetworkStream
   Public Sub Run_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Run.Click
    'Telnet

    MYtcpClient = New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
    MytcpClient.Connect(mstag.Text, 23)
    MyNetworkStream = MYtcpClient.GetStream()


    If MyNetworkStream.CanWrite And MyNetworkStream.CanRead Then
        Dim bytes(MYtcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
        MyNetworkStream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(MYtcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize))
        Dim returndata As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
        telnetout.Text = returndata
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub sissend_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles sissend.Click

 MyNetworkStream.Write(myWriteBuffer, 0, myWriteBuffer.Length)

    Dim bytes(MYtcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
    MyNetworkStream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(MYtcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize))
    Dim returndata As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
    telnetout.Text = returndata
End Sub
End Class
```

---

### Removed Public Class Myform

```
Public Class Main




Private Sub txt1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mstag.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbl1.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub devicepage_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles devicepage.DocumentCompleted

End Sub


    Private SIS As System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
    Private netdata As NetworkStream
    Private Sub Run_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Run.Click


        Dim msnumber As String = mstag.Text

        'Ping Code

        Try
            Dim ping As Ping = New Ping()
            Dim ping2 As Ping = New Ping()
            Dim ping3 As Ping = New Ping()
            Dim ping4 As Ping = New Ping()
            Dim pingreply As PingReply = ping.Send(mstag.Text + ".regent.edu")
            Dim pingreply2 As PingReply = ping2.Send(mstag.Text + ".regent.edu")
            Dim pingreply3 As PingReply = ping3.Send(mstag.Text + ".regent.edu")
            Dim pingreply4 As PingReply = ping4.Send(mstag.Text + ".regent.edu")
            Dim avgadd As Integer = pingreply.RoundtripTime + pingreply2.RoundtripTime + pingreply3.RoundtripTime + pingreply4.RoundtripTime
            Dim avg As Integer = avgadd / 4
            pingresults.Text &= "Ping Time: " & pingreply.RoundtripTime & "ms" & vbNewLine
            pingresults.Text &= "Ping Time: " & pingreply2.RoundtripTime & "ms" & vbNewLine
            pingresults.Text &= "Ping Time: " & pingreply3.RoundtripTime & "ms" & vbNewLine
            pingresults.Text &= "Ping Time: " & pingreply4.RoundtripTime & "ms" & vbNewLine
            pingresults.Text &= "Average Time: " & (avg) & "ms"

        Catch err As Exception
            pingresults.Text = "Ping Timeout"
        End Try


        'NSLOOKUP Code

        Try
            Dim p As New Process
            With p.StartInfo
                .FileName = "nslookup.exe"
                .Arguments = mstag.Text
                .CreateNoWindow = True
                .RedirectStandardOutput = True
                .RedirectStandardError = True
                .UseShellExecute = False
            End With

            p.Start()
            If p.WaitForExit(5000) Then
                'Read Output
                Dim reader As StreamReader = p.StandardOutput
                Dim output As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
                nslookupresults.Text = output

            Else
                'Failed
                nslookupresults.Text = ("Failed: Timeout")
            End If

        Catch err As Exception
            nslookupresults.Text = "Timeout. :("
        End Try

        'Telnet

        SIS = New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
        SIS.Connect(mstag.Text, 23)
        netdata = SIS.GetStream()

        If netdata.CanWrite And netdata.CanRead Then
            Dim bytes(SIS.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
            netdata.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(SIS.ReceiveBufferSize))
            Dim returndata As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
            telnetout.Text = returndata
        End If

    End Sub


    Public Sub sissend_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles sissend.Click


        Dim myWriteBuffer As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(telnetinput.Text)
        netdata.Write(myWriteBuffer, 0, myWriteBuffer.Length)

        Dim bytes(SIS.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
        netdata.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(SIS.ReceiveBufferSize))
        Dim returndata As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
        telnetout.Text = returndata
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This definitely fixed that issue but now it is calling 'SIS' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. FYI I updated post with new code. @i'mstartingtohatethissite

Comment: There is no instance of  TcpClient or networkstream declared in that routine. If you want only declare it once and keep it open then you'll need to declare in your class or module namespace.

Comment: Will a new instance close the current connection? The second button is to send additional data. Thank you again for helping.

Comment: The instance you created is no longer referenced after the procedure is finished executing, since the variable was declared inside of the routine. The garbage collector will eventually find and release it from memory.

Comment: So the connection is basically temporary. For a long term connection, declare that object outside of a routine.

Comment: So I did all of that and It introduced a lot of other errors. Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference. On objects that are references from the design. Namely mstag.text and telnetout.text

Comment: Could you post your code please including the namespace?

Comment: Ok, I assumed so. The MyForm was basically supposed to represent your class "Main". By including that you have declared a new class inside of your class. Delete the Public Class Myform and one of the calls to End Class.

Comment: Holy cow its all happy. :) thanks a ton. Like I said I'm still new and very appreciative of the help. They need a tip button on here.

Comment: Hey guy, I make this suggestion to people often. A website called Learnvb.net will teach you so many things that you didn't know you needed to learn. Nearly all on video and worth the very small fee. A good way to learn just how easy it is to make very powerful applications with VB.